# Debian update confuses GRUB with md0 not sda1

Tags: debian, grub

I removed a software RAID setup on a server I took over several years ago and everything worked fine until I upgraded the kernel the other day. It seems when debian updated the grub menu.lst file it not only added the new kernel with md0 but also the old kernel as md0.

What is causing debian to think there is still a software RAID setup? Is there a default file I need to change, do I need to remove the mdadm package?

Comment: that's in /proc/mounts?

Comment: "what's in /proc/mounts?" even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some slightly non-specific Debian information..

- Make sure that `/etc/fstab` contains no mention of the MD devices.
  I would presume that it doesn't, as you are able to otherwise boot.
- Debian appears to perform some magic with `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.
  Check whether it contains an entry akin to this and re-run `update-grub`.

  > `#kopt=root=/dev/sda1`
- If you are definitely no longer using SW RAID at all then you can remove mdadm.
  Debian may use it's presence as a hook when updating GRUB.

Comment: +1 This looks mostly useful, but a pint for lunch is clouding my judgement slightly. All sensible things to check.

Comment: It was the kopt that was causing problems. Cheers